# Powershell commands executed with echo?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

Why is it that commands like this are often shown as being executing by echoing them?  Typically echo would just treat the contents as a string and print it to output, which wouldn't execute it. Additionally, hash being the symbol for commenting out a command, makes this doubly confusing:

```bsh
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=curProjVersion;isOutput=true]1.4.5"
```

Comment: The `echo` (a built-in alias for `Write-Output`) is superfluous in this command (due to PowerShell's _implicit_ output feature); it does indeed only output a _string_ - only that string getting parsed and interpreted by another command / engine (the format is Azure-specific, not PowerShell syntax) could result in execution (leaving aside that you can embed entire commands in expandable strings (`"..."`) via  `$(...)`, the subexpression operator, which is not the case in your string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure DevOps is listening to standard output of your task and interprets them when it finds the tag `##vso` at the beginning of the line.

This is not something that is special to Powershell, you could set you variable from a js file like this:

```js
console.log("##vso[task.setvariable variable=curProjVersion;isOutput=true]1.4.5");
```

All that matters is the standard output of your task.

Comment: Ah, I wondered if it was something like that.  Thanks.  I assume VSO is legacy for "Visual Studio Online"?

Comment: Yes, the tag come from the old name.

Answer (score -3):

Echo is a throwback to unix and bash.  Echo is also nice way to output an array of strings without any quoting or commas.

```
echo one two three four
one
two
three
four
```